# Countletters(sorted)

Tags: python, string, count

Following is my coding for count letters and i need  the output as

```
[('e', 1), ('g', 2), ('l', 1), ('o', 2)]
```

and my out put is

```
[('e', 1), ('g', 2), ('g', 2), ('l', 1), ('o', 2), ('o', 2)]
```

This is my code

```
def countLetters(word):
    word=list(word)
    word.sort()
    trans=[]
    for j in word:
        row=[]
        a=word.count(j)
        row.append(j)
        row.append(a)
        trans.append(tuple(row))
    return trans
```

can anyone explain me, how to get the expected output with my code?
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

**Example:**

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter("Foobar")
print sorted(c.items())
```

**Output:**

> [('F', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('o', 2), ('r', 1)]

---

Another way is to use a `dict`, or better, a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (when running python 2.6 or lower, since `Counter` was added in Python 2.7)

**Example:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

def countLetters(word):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for j in word:
        d[j] += 1
    return sorted(d.items())

print countLetters("Foobar")
```

**Output:**

> [('F', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('o', 2), ('r', 1)]

---

Or use a simple list comprehension

```
word = "Foobar"
print sorted((letter, word.count(letter)) for letter in set(word))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('google')
Counter({'o': 2, 'g': 2, 'e': 1, 'l': 1})
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(Counter('google').items(), key=itemgetter(0))
[('e', 1), ('g', 2), ('l', 1), ('o', 2)]
>>>
```

Actually, there is no need for `key`:

```
>>> sorted(Counter('google').items())
[('e', 1), ('g', 2), ('l', 1), ('o', 2)]
```

As tuples are sorted first by the first item, then by the second, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
def countLetters(word):
    k=[]
    Listing=[]
    Cororo=[]
    for warm in word:
        if warm not in k:
            k.append(warm) 
    for cold in range(len(k)):
        word.count(k[cold])
        Listing.append(word.count(k[cold]))
        Cororo.append((k[cold],Listing[cold]))
    return sorted(Cororo)
```

This is a bit of an old fashion way of doing this since you can use the counter module like the guy above me and make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code like this (Python 2.5+):

```
def countLetters(word):
    word=list(word)
    word.sort()
    trans=[]
    for j in word:
        row=[]
        a=word.count(j)
        row.append(j)
        row.append(a)
        trans.append(tuple(row))
    ans = list(set(trans))
    ans.sort()
    return ans
```

Comment: This code is bad in many ways. First of all, it is quite long and does things which built-in python classes do better (look at `Counter`). Then, it's sorting stuff twice, which is unnecessary. Also, the variable `row` and the call to `tuple` is also unnecessary, since you could just use `trans.append((j, word.count(j)))`.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Yes, a more Pythonic solution would have been better, but this is just an answer that doesn't require too many changes from OP's code.

Comment: @irrelephant Didn't say it was your fault :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not accounting for the duplicate occurrence of the letters in your `j` loop

I think a quick fix will be to modify the iteration as `for j in set(word)`.

This ensures each letter is iterated once.

Comment: You'd still have to sort your final answer as set doesn't guarantee order (assuming that the OP's example is not just a coincidence).

Answer (score -2):

`trans = list(set(trans))`

Converting a `list` to a `set` removes duplicates (which I think is what you want to do).

Comment: The OP wants to count the number of occurrences of each letter in the word - removing duplicates would produce false results.